# How to specify Slave name as build parameter in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I have a jenkins job on my master node from this job I will specify the name of the slave node as a build Parameter.In the job configuration I am using Subversion Source Code Management.So when I build my job on master node I want the job to place the files from Subversion to my given slave node folder.Is it possible to do do in Jenkins.If yes that what set of plugins do I need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Node Label parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)